# CentOS 7 default extras repository doesn't contain any packages

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to install the `epel-release` package from the CentOS extras repository, but the repository seems to be empty. (I'm also pretty new to linux)

When I run `yum repolist`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repo id                          repo name                             status
base/7/i386                      CentOS-7 - Base                       7,114
extras/7/i386                    CentOS-7 - Extras                         0
updates/7/i386                   CentOS-7 - Updates                    1,437
repolist: 8,551
```

When I run `yum list extras`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
```

I have tried running `yum clean all` and `yum update`, but nothing has seemed to work.

Output of `hostnamectl`:

```
 Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
       Icon name: computer-vm
         Chassis: vm
      Machine ID: 4925cfdbb53e4e18b5ce1e3bd2d4ce0d
         Boot ID: b3109364c8a14af9b37a81599f900755
  Virtualization: oracle
Operating System: CentOS 7 (AltArch)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
          Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.centos.plus.i686
    Architecture: x86
```

Output of `rpm --query centos-release`:

```
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

`yum list extras` is actually a regular yum command. What you are looking for is probably `repoquery -a --repoid=extras`. The "repoquery" command is part of the "yum-utils" package.

Comment: Or  `yum list available | grep 'extras $'`

Comment: Both commands produce no output for me. I think it's not a problem with yum, but somehow the system can't grab the list of packages.

Comment: Perhaps try a reinstall of yum and yum-utils? `yum -y reinstall yum yum-utils` then rebuild the rpm database with `rpm --rebuilddb`.

Comment: EPEL i386 https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_EPEL_Repository_on_CentOS → `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/i386/e/epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm` ... No extras http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/extras/i386/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

`epel.repo` is also at EPEL https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL → → https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm ... Besides that: The package *is* in extras/ too.

Install the downloaded epel.repo # `cd Downloads/ && yum install epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm`

About the "yum repolist" : Don't know what the "extras/7/i386" is about. There aren't any: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/ >>> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/extras/ ... There are four .i686 packages. + 268 .noarch . And: Are you sure that extras is set to enabled=1 ? My `yum repolist` is this ( CentOS 7.3-1611 ) :

```
repo id                  repo name                                      status
!base/7/x86_64           CentOS-7 - Base                                9,360+3
!centos-sclo-rh/x86_64   CentOS-7 - SCLo rh                               5,174
!centos-sclo-sclo/x86_64 CentOS-7 - SCLo sclo                               403
!epel/x86_64             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  11,722
!extras/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Extras                                  380
!updates/7/x86_64        CentOS-7 - Updates                               1,838
repolist: 28,877
```

A copy of latest CentOS-Base.repo is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSG10b0lXeTUtRzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a way to fix my extras repo? I've added my specs to the main post.

Comment: Please see my edited post : A copy of `CentOS-Base.repo` was uploaded. .... I didn't know about any i686 version of CentOS 7.

Comment: Found the "CentOS 7 (AltArch)" : http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/ . Probably installed because your host OS is 32bits.